# Media card reader not working in 16.04.1

Tags: drivers, mount, sd-card

Tried on two separate systems: Compaq nc6320 and a Lenovo T530... same results
Ubuntu 14.04... SD media cards on both systems work as expected (specifically SD reader)

Upgrade both systems to 16.04.1 and neither system detects a SD media card when inserted.

Reverted to 14.04 because this is nonsense!

Lspci indicates they are Texas Instruments PCIxx12 cardbus controller (nc6320) and the T530 indicates it is a Ricoh Co Ltd MMC/SD host controller (rev 07)

(almost makes Windows hardware detection a benefit) At least it works!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe inserting a sd card into the internal card reader is just not recognized by the system. Try the following:

Boot the system with the SD card in the SD card reader. Maybe this will lead to a mounted device. As alternative, on a running system insert the sd card and execute

```
sudo sh -c 'echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/rescan'
```

to rescan the devices.

For further investigation you could post the output of `lspci -v` with the card in (just the relevant bit regarding the sd card reader) and the output of `dmesg` when inserting the card.